# Working with Function have_posts from WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with the function have_posts from WordPress codex. What I'm trying to do is:

```
while ($content_query->have_posts()) {

         $content_query->the_post();
         if(strpos(the_title(),'Garajes Gran')===false){        
            global $post;
            include($item_template);

         }

        }
```

So I get a full list of names with Garajes Gran names included and not the list without the name Garajes Gran, What I'm doing wrong?. Also instead of look for the first position where the String Garajes Gran it's, it prints all names, so why  *if(strpos(the_title(),'Garajes Gran')===false){*  doesn't do what it means?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo` or `print_r` the variable, values you use and check whether they do have the value you expect them to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code used 'get_the_title()' instead of 'the_title()'.

```
if(strpos(get_the_title( get_the_ID() ),'Garajes Gran')===false){        
    global $post;
    include($item_template);
}
```

I hope this is working for you.